# Why can unsafe code not move-out non-copy types from behind a raw pointer?

Tags: rust, initialization, undefined-behavior, raw-pointer

The Rust language disallows unsafe code from moving-out non-copy types from behind a raw pointer, reporting a compilation error for the following program:

```rust
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;

struct NonCopyType(u32);

fn main() {
    let unsafe_cell = UnsafeCell::new(NonCopyType(123));
    
    let ptr = unsafe_cell.get();

    // Disallowed, but the code will never access
    // the uninitialized unsafe cell after this.
    let _ = unsafe { *ptr };
}
```

Compilation error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*ptr` which is behind a raw pointer
  --> src/main.rs:12:22
   |
12 |     let _ = unsafe { *ptr };
   |                      ^^^^ move occurs because `*ptr` has type `NonCopyType`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

What is the motivation of that error message? Is it because moving-out non-copy types from behind a raw pointer is error prone, even if the developer declared that he's expert enough to write unsafe code? Or is there some undefined behavior in the above program that I'm missing?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [`std::ptr::read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.read.html)?

Comment: `std::ptr::read` would allow me to read a non-copy type from behind a raw pointer, yes, but I'm still wondering why moving a non-copy type from behind a raw pointer is a compilation error.

Comment: Consider this: how do you imagine the behavior of "moving a non-copy type from behind a raw reference" would differ from that of `std::ptr::read()`? In Rust a "move" is exactly the same as copy, except that it invalidates the original (prevents its from getting used and from getting dropped). How can the compiler do that if the original is behind a pointer, i.e. owned by someone else, possibly in an unrelated part of code?

Comment: I voted to close this as opinion-based since I doubt there is a concrete answer to the question is "why doesn't Rust allows you to use the deref operator to move out of a raw pointer".

Comment: Filled a diagnostics issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/92834

Comment: "In Rust a move is exactly the same as copy, except that it invalidates the original" That makes sense, thanks. So, the error message is because the compiler cannot later precisely detect whether the value behind a raw pointer has already been moved out, but the move analysis at the same time must be sound and never allow the code to use maybe-moved-out values.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the motivation of that error message?

The safety invariants that a programmer must uphold in order to apply the dereference operator to a raw pointer are only that the pointer be dereferenceable.  Where additional guarantees must be upheld (e.g. never using the referenced value again), Rust requires that some method with those requirements be used instead.

In this case, as loganfsmyth commented, there is [`std::ptr::read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.read.html); or there's the inherent [`read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.read) method on the raw pointer types themselves.  Thus:

```rust
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;

struct NonCopyType(u32);

fn main() {
    let unsafe_cell = UnsafeCell::new(NonCopyType(123));
    let ptr = unsafe_cell.get();
    let _ = unsafe { ptr.read() };
}
```

> Is it because moving-out non-copy types from behind a raw pointer is error prone, even if the developer declared that he's expert enough to write unsafe code?

`unsafe` has nothing to do with expertise, and everything to do with taking responsibility for upholding certain invariants that the compiler would otherwise check for you; being explicit about the invariants each method requires to be upheld, and that each caller is upholding, is absolutely key to getting this right.

Rust could, I suppose, have overloaded the safety requirements of the dereference operator so that programmers need uphold different invariants depending on context.  But that would be a horrible footgun, and make reasoning about the code extremely painful both for the person writing it and anyone who later reads it.